# custom element error in jointjs when use vue-cli

Tags: vue-cli, jointjs

I got an error when use my element in vue-cli.

**I do not why joint.shapes do not contain my element!**

**test.vue:**
     **// Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined"**

```
 <script>

        const joint = require('jointjs');

        joint.dia.Element.define('example.Component', {
            attrs: {
              ...
            },
        }, {
            markup: ...,
        }, {
            createComponent: function() {
            return new this({
                attrs:{
                  ...
                }
            });
            }
        });

        export default {
            name: "FlowCanvas",
            mounted() {
                var graph=new joint.dia.Graph;
                var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                   ...
                });
                var el1=joint.shapes.example.Component.createComponent();

                el1.position(100,100);

            },
        }
    </script>
```